# Can I force a user to upgrade my app in Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

We have project requirement where we need to force the user to upgrade the app in android and iOS both. And the application we have developed using the Hybrid technology phonegap + dojo.

I have few question with respect to that

1. Is it possible to make the user upgrade the app as soon as he opens the application
2. If yes then is there any API's available to perform this task in Android and iOS.
3. Is there any restriction from Apple and Android to make user upgrade forcefully.

Please can anyone help me in this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Not if they don't want to. With mobile devices some people are sensitive about rationing out their limited bandwidth so there would be a small uproar if this was allowed.

It may be a bit late now if your app has already left the stable, but would it not be more user friendly for your app to check for updates and gently inform the user that if they do not update then the app will not be able to function until they do. If a user truly doesn't care about that sort of thing there are settings on there device to allow updates automaticly

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this, but you can create a service that returns the version number of the latest allowed app or something to that effect, that can get checked on application launch and if it does not match you can ask the users to update.

I'm not sure if Apple/Google have any restrictions on this, but I've worked on a project that does this and there weren't any issues on either platform.

The only catch here is that if you already have an app in store then this might not be so feasible.

So to answer your questions:

1. No
2. No
3. Not 100% certain, but I don't think so.